# Function only defined but immediately executed anyway

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick

I'm having trouble with a short javascript code in my file ajaxrequest.js . Here it is :

```
function afficher () {
  $.post('requete_affichage.php', function (data) {
    $('#name-data').text(data); });
}

$('#bouton2').on('click', afficher());
```

So the problem is the function immediately executes and inserts the data in the div#name-data field of my index.html page as soon as i hit "localhost" in my browser, and doesn't wait for my click on #bouton2 to do so. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

By including the brackets after the function you are telling it to execute immediately. To assign the function reference to the click handler, remove the brackets:

```
$('#bouton2').on('click', afficher);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried that, but i doesn't work either :/

Comment: It should do. Have you checked the console for any errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: It doesn't execute immediately, but it still doesn't work on the click

Comment: Chrome's developer tools says no problem

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of the issue, as I am unable to replicate it: http://jsfiddle.net/35gr9dsg/

Comment: You can debug by adding a `console.log` at the top of your `afficher` function and checking if it shows in your browser console on click.
Bearing in mind jQuery needs to have been fully loaded (checked using $(function(){ // your code });, or has been loaded after the element) to bind to it like you have.